# Change Size of button in the middle of a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, image, button, uiscrollview, center

I have a uiscrollview that contain several buttons. When the user scrolld a button to the middle of the scrollview I need to change the size of it. I have created and added the buttons programmatically and assigned them each a tag number. I am just not sure how to determine which button is in the middle so that I can change it. Has any one done something like this?

Comment: Use scrollView.contentOffset and compare it to each of your button's frame.origin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following code where you want to check if the button is in the center of the scrollView.

```
for (UIView *view in scrollView.subviews) {

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

        CGRect visibleRect = CGRectMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentOffset.y, scrollView.frame.size.height, scrollView.frame.size.width);
        CGRect centerRect = CGRectInset(visibleRect, 30, 30);
        BOOL isCentered = CGRectIntersectsRect(view.frame, centerRect);

        if (isCentered) {
            // the button is centered in the scroll view...
        }
    }

}
```

isCentered will now tell you if the button is centered in the scrollview. You'll have to change the 30 value to whatever is appropriate for the size of your scrollView.

Comment: I have this working except that the center points are not in the center of the visible scrollview it seems to be more towards the left side. The scrollview is 320w x 105h, and the button is 50w x 50h. I also am checking inside the scrollViewDidScroll delegate. Any ideas on how to get more in the center of the scrollview and not so far to the left?  Thank you again for helping me with this, you saved my a few hours for sure.